# Converting a list to an array

Tags: tcl

Consider the sample code below, i need to convert the list "nvlist" back to an array. How can i do that?

```
for {set i 0} { $i < 3} {incr i} {
    set color($i) $i    
}
set nvList [array get color]
```

I have the data in nvlist after this, and i need to change this back to an array.. How can i do this?

Comment: Having seen your questions, you are aware that Tcl arrays are _associative_ arrays? They have no natural element order. Tcl's ordered data type is the list (or the dictionary, from 8.5 onwards and then only in a very particular sense).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array get` and `array set` are inverses:

```
set dict [array get myArr]
array set myArrCopy $dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you actually already have in an array called "color", so in theory you need to do nothing. :-)